# Makedirs is creating a file not a folder

Tags: python, input, directory, io

I am having an issue where when I try to make a folder it makes a file instead. Specifically it occurs in the variable folder. Code is as follows and I am using python 2.7

```
import os

i = False
while i != True:
    fil = raw_input("Enter Filename Here: ")
    i = os.path.exists(fil)
    if i == False: print("File does not exist! Try Again.")

folder = raw_input("Enter Output Folder Here: ")
try:
    os.path.exists(folder)
except:
    if not os.path.exists(folder):
        print("Creating Folder for You.")
        os.makedirs(folder)

output = raw_input("Enter Chlorophyll-a Output Filename Here: ")
full = os.path.join(folder, output)

if os.path.exists(full):
    yesno = raw_input("Output file already exists are you sure you want to overwrite? Yes/No: ")
    if yesno == "Yes":
        k = open(full, "w")
    if yesno == "No":
        raise SystemExit("Exiting File Now!")
if not os.path.exists(full):
    print ("File Does Not Exist. I Will Make It For You.")
    k = open(full, "w")
```

On my computer I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/---/.PyCharmCE2019.2/config/scratches/scratch_6.py", line 33, in <module>
    k = open(full, "w")
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong? I cannot seem to figure it out

Comment: What do you mean by 'it makes a file instead'? os.makedirs can't make a file. Is it making a folder that has a file extension?

Comment: For some reason when I run this code, it does not make a folder at all but just a empty file which is definitely not a folder directory. It does not create a brand new folder at all, just an empty file.

Comment: What path did you type in when running the script?

Comment: For my input just an excel xlsm file C:/Users/---/documents/excelfile.xlsx. For my output folder I did C:/Users/---/Desktop/output. In which output is a folder that does not exist and one I want to create.

Comment: You seem to misunderstand how os.path.exists work. It returns True or False depending on whether the path you give it already exists or not. It does NOT THROW AN EXCEPTION, so the except: clause where you are creating the folder is never actually executed.

Answer (score 0):

You never create the folder, in

```
try:
    os.path.exists(folder)
except:
    if not os.path.exists(folder):
        print("Creating Folder for You.")
        os.makedirs(folder)
```

You are trying to create the folder if `os.path.exists` throws an exception, but it doesn't, it return `True` or `False`, and later on you create the file in

```
k = open(full, "w")
```

Use it like that

```
folder = raw_input("Enter Output Folder Here: ")

if not os.path.exists(folder):
    print("Creating Folder for You.")
    os.makedirs(folder)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are implementing with this code, but I've made some changes to your code. I think this will help you.

```
import os

fil = input("Enter Filename Here: ")
if not os.path.exists(fil):
    print("File doesn't exist!")

    folder = input("Enter Output Folder Here: ")
    if not os.path.exists(folder):
        print("Creating folder for you.")
        os.makedirs(folder)

    output = input("Enter Chlorophyll-a Output Filename Here: ")
    full = os.path.join(folder, output)

    if os.path.exists(full):
        yesno = input("Output file already exists are you sure you want to overwrite? Yes/No: ")
        if yesno == "Yes":
            k = open(full, "w")
            k.close()
        if yesno == "No":
            raise SystemExit("Exiting File Now!")
    else:
        print ("File Does Not Exist. I Will Make It For You.")
        k = open(full, "w")
        k.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your code does not create a directory when it **does not** exist. Consider:

```
try:
    os.path.exists(folder)
except:
    if not os.path.exists(folder):
        print("Creating Folder for You.")
        os.makedirs(folder)
```

In the try block, you call `os.path.exists(folder)`, but that does not generate any exception. That means the code in the except clause does not get executed. What you want is to create the directory regardless that it exists and just ignore the error:

```
try:
    os.makedirs(folder)
except OSError:
    pass
```